# How do I use select in loop continue when statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to continue a oracle sql loop when I find more then one result in a query - so my simplified code:

```
declare
   cursor foo_cursor select * from foo_table;
   foo foo_cursor%ROWTYPE;
begin 
   open foo_cursor;
   loop 
      fetch foo_cursor into foo;
      exit when foo_cursor%NOTFOUND;
      continue when ( -- the next query has entries or an entry, 
                      -- but how do I do this?
         select count(*) from bar_table where bar_column=foo.foo_column
             group by bar_column having count(1)>1;
      )
      insert into uninterresting_table (some_column) VALUES
          (foo.foo_column);
    end loop;
    close foo_cursor;
end;
```

Comment: That is irrelevant. The select has either none or one and more entries, if the later happens i want go into the next iteration else do more stuff in this iteration. The select could also look quite different. But for your interest - I want to go into next itteration if I find under specific conditions more then one entry. I don't need the count result any further.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you only want to act on the records in `FOO_TABLE` when at least two related records exists in `BAR_TABLE`.  You can alter the definition of `foo_cursor` to take that requirement into account as shown below.  That way you don't need to iteratively check for the existence of a record in `BAR_TABLE` each time.

```
declare
   cursor foo_cursor is 
   select * 
     from foo_table foo
    where exists (select 1 from bar_table bar
                   where bar.bar_column = foo.foo_column
                  having count(*) > 1);
   foo foo_cursor%ROWTYPE;
begin 
   open foo_cursor;
   loop 
      fetch foo_cursor into foo;
      exit when foo_cursor%NOTFOUND;
      insert into uninteresting_table (some_column) VALUES
          (foo.foo_column);
    end loop;
    close foo_cursor;
end;
/
```

On the other hand if you are looking to skip records in `FOO_TABLE` that already have two or more records in `BAR_TABLE`, you can just invert the existence check and all else would be the same:

```
declare
   cursor foo_cursor is 
   select * 
     from foo_table foo
    where NOT exists (select 1 from bar_table bar
                       where bar.bar_column = foo.foo_column
                      having count(*) > 1);
   foo foo_cursor%ROWTYPE;
begin 
   open foo_cursor;
   loop 
      fetch foo_cursor into foo;
      exit when foo_cursor%NOTFOUND;
      insert into uninteresting_table (some_column) VALUES
          (foo.foo_column);
    end loop;
    close foo_cursor;
end;
/
```

If you want to process all records in `FOO_TABLE` but do additional actions when two or more records exist in `BAR_TABLE`, you can still do that with a change to your `foo_cursor`:

```
declare
   cursor foo_cursor is 
   select foo.* 
        , case when exists (select 1 from bar_table bar
                             where bar.bar_column = foo.foo_column
                            having count(*) > 1)
               then 'Y'
               else 'N'
          end has_two_or_more
     from foo_table foo;
   foo foo_cursor%ROWTYPE;
begin 
   open foo_cursor;
   loop 
      fetch foo_cursor into foo;
      exit when foo_cursor%NOTFOUND;
      continue when foo.has_two_or_more = 'Y';
      insert into uninteresting_table (some_column) VALUES
          (foo.foo_column);
    end loop;
    close foo_cursor;
end;
/
```

Comment: Thanks @Sentinel, I did not know such an Exists Clause is possible

Comment: Also thanks your's and the other answer helped a lot. So now it is also clear how to do it with my original control structue and yes well, I can also use the exists/not exists clause - that I should have seen myself :( but I like also my structure with continue as my cursor select is allready a monster and I think with my constrol sturcture it is better to understand and to care for by others. But again many thanks. So my actual simplified code will follow.

Answer (score 1):

> if the [select has ... one and more entries] i want go into the next iteration else do more stuff in this iteration.

If there are no records in `bar_table` you want to do some more processing otherwise you want to skip the processing. There's a way to do that: `goto`.

Oh yes :)

```
declare
   cursor foo_cursor select * from foo_table;
   foo foo_cursor%ROWTYPE;
   n pls_integer;
begin 
   open foo_cursor;
   loop 
      fetch foo_cursor into foo;
      exit when foo_cursor%NOTFOUND;
      select count(*) into n
      from bar_table 
      where bar_column=foo.foo_column
      group by bar_column having count(1)>1;

      if n > 0 then
         goto skip_point;
      end if;

      insert into uninterresting_table (some_column) VALUES
          (foo.foo_column);

      << skip_point >>
    end loop;
    close foo_cursor;
end;
```

Obviously you could just put the whole skippable section into a branch of an IF .. ELSE statement, but where's the fun in that?

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to @APC and @Sentinel -- I still made my version work, but your answers gave me the right dirrections:

````
declare
   cursor foo_cursor select * from foo_table;
   foo foo_cursor%ROWTYPE;
   n pls_integer
begin 
   open foo_cursor;
   loop 
      fetch foo_cursor into foo;
      exit when foo_cursor%NOTFOUND;
      begin
         select count(1) into n from bar_table where bar_column=foo.foo_column
             group by bar_column;
         exception when NO_DATA_FOUND then continue;
      end
      continue when (n>1);
      insert into uninterresting_table (some_column) VALUES
          (foo.foo_column);
      -- do some more stuff
    end loop;
    close foo_cursor;
end;
```
````